# How to create user accessible controls(Like labels, Buttons..) dynamically Using Windows Application (C#)

Tags: c#

1.Need to create Dynamically controls like Labels, Buttons.
2.After created dynamically control(label,button),that I can able to select that control and moving to other location on that form.

Comment: Will you be so kind and also provide the GUI-Toolkit you intend to use?

Comment: What are you missing to finish this task?

Answer (score 1):

This is a large question and it's impossible to give you a short answer.

There is a quite good sample for a starting point available at [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823293/Windows-Form-Design-at-Run-Time) and [csharpcorner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/asmabegam/windows-form-design-at-run-time/). Version #2 of this sample is also [available](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/898669/Easy-Form-Design-at-Run-Time-Csharp-Winform).

There is also WPF designer available at [github](https://github.com/icsharpcode/WpfDesigner).